# How can I convert this .eps file to pdf / something more widely used?

Tags: image-format

I've gotten errors when I attempted to use Inkscape, GIMP, and Uniconverter because I don't have access to the proprietary software.  Perhaps the file corrupt?  Thanks for any advice, this is a charitable cause ("Feed my Starving Children") if that is extra motivation for you!

I'm trying to convert the .eps which is part of this [.zip](http://www.fmsc.org/document.doc?id=260).  Another way to get to the file is to start [here](http://www.fmsc.org/mobilepack/promotion-toolkit), and scroll down to the three "Mobile Pack Logos"

Comment: I think it's worth noting that EPS is still the most commonly used format for distribution of vector artwork elements like logos. Also, do you actually need to open the file? Normally you'd place it in a layout.

Comment: Also worth noting that EPS isn't exactly proprietary (it is PostScript, but plenty of software can deal with it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to successfully convert the file to PDF [using this online tool](http://docupub.com/pdfconvert/) and it retained the vector graphics.

I was then able to successfully open that PDF in Inkscape and edit as paths.

Unfortunately I didn't have the font that it uses on the bottom but it's Myriad Pro so not hard to find and you may have it already :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some great free websites for converting `eps` files, I like [epsconvert.com](http://www.epsconvert.com/) - you can convert to `jpg`, `gif` and `png` formats. You can even resize the graphic!

Answer (score 1):

As a person who commonly writes EPS by hand heres how I deal with eps files. Mostly nearly every graphics and desktop publishing app can deal with eps. It being the second most common vector format available on the planet  (after pdf, but then pdf is a direct descendant of eps).

So you can open eps in Word, Open office, mathematica, inkscape, gimp, corel draw... and because its the primary tech behind adobe in all adobe apps as well as nearly half of all mediun end printers.

Unfortunately eps is not a simple format so all kinds of convolutions may apply. For example font data may be omitted, or it may use advanced features not available to you. Most commonly you can deal with this by using Ghostscripts ps2ps command.

The other standard way is to just distill the eps to pdf with either Ghostscript or acrobat Distiller. This removes all the dynamic features of eps and flattens the graphic.

Answer (score 0):

**pstoedit** is good for working back and forth with vector graphics.  It relies on Ghostscript (or GSView in Windows), and can be integrated with GSView.  You can get everything from [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/index.htm) and the extensive capability of pstoedit can be found [here](http://www.pstoedit.net/pstoedit/).

Comment: The pstoedit link you posted is broken.